# Mirror not working properly on a circle

Tags: mirror

I am doing a 3D Anime Character for Blender 2.78c, but when I try to use the mirror on the eye, here is the result:[image: problem with Mirror modifier]

Could anyone please help?

Comment: I see the blue Z axis line in the middle, so it seems well mirrored around X or Y axis (you are not showing which). please show more of the scene setup, possibly with mirror modifier settings

Comment: The issue here is the fact that you didnt move the origin of your object at the center of the face, the mirror modifier is according to the symmetry axe ( It's the line set by X, Y or Z in the modifier panel, cutting the origin of your object). So, in object mode, put the origin of your object at the center of the face, set up your modifier, and then, move your object's vectices in Edit mode according to your background picture. I hope that will help you ;).

Comment: OK, I see where I went wrong. Thanks for the help.